# How does a sensitivity list work in circuit level?

Tags: verilog, clock

Let's say there's a code that runs like this

```
reg [4:0] data; 
always @ (posedge clk, posedge clr)
    begin
        if(clr)
             data <= 0;
        else
             data <= data +1;
    end
```

How would this look like in circuit level? My guess is roughly
[image]

but then that wouldn't help if Clk goes from 0 to 1 while Clr is 1......

Also, is it good practice to have multiple elements in the sensitivity list? From what I see, there's som overhead going on here..

Comment: Note that an async control (CLR here) will never gate a clock, which will be driven directly, without the OR2. Part of your confusion is probably that the clear is described with a `posedge`, but this is basically a limitation of the language.

Answer (score 4):

Verilog excerpt will infer DFF (D Flip-Flop) with async reset. This happens due to the fact that reset signal is a part of sensitivity list.

NOTE1: as per LRM for Verilog, adding the reset to the sensitivity list is what makes the reset asynchronous.

NOTE2: each Verilog procedural block should model only one type of flip-flop. In other words, a designer should not mix resetable (sync or async) flip-flops with follower flip-flops (flops with no resets) in the same procedural block.

Your diagram is incorrect, 'clr' signal will be connected to extra input of the DFF called as CLEAR (it is basically an async reset). I suggest to start with some sort of Verilog tutorial, this is very basic thing and it is well explained in materials that are generally available. To grasp on concept of reset in HDL code I recommend the following material:
http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2003Boston_Resets.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The schematic is not accurate. 4 D-FF will be implemented for each bit of data declared. 
Adding reset (i.e. clr) to sensitivity list will make the ckt async (Verilog LRM). 
The D-FF will have an additional clear pin, there will be NO bubble to this pin as your reset (i.e. clr) is active high.